# can i install intel HAXM even if my processor does not support virtualization?

Tags: android, hyper-v, haxm

My laptop uses Intel core Duo CPU T5750 processor which supports Enable bit functionality but does not support virtualization.

Can I still install HAXM by just disabling the Hyper-V feature?

Will Haxm run in my laptop which doesn't support virtualization??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It will not run, he absolutely needs Virtualization, the Hyper-V feature has nothing to do here. Sadly, your processor is getting old.

BTW, use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), far better emulator than stock one.

Comment: what is genymotion? will that work as an emulator in android studio??will my processor support it?

Comment: Genymotion is another Android emulator, which runs on top of VirtualBox. Generally, it will run faster than stock Android emulator. And yes, you can use it with Android Studio. Your processor must be supported, let's give a try

Comment: genymotion did not solve my problem!! it juz showing an error again!